# Is there a Cyber-Cafe program for server-client places (Internet Cafe)

Tags: remote-control, cybercafe

Is there a program for Ubuntu that can be used to control the time for the clients in an Internet Cafe or Cyber Cafe. Similar to Cyber Control and others. It blocks the Clients PC until a client comes and starts a timer after which is blocks again.

Comment: part of setting up a cyber-cafe would be configuring the browser. For how to do that, you can take a look at this - http://askubuntu.com/questions/46957/how-do-i-set-up-an-opera-web-kiosk

Comment: You might want to look at [Use Ubuntu for a public computer in a library](http://askubuntu.com/q/868/6969) as well.

Comment: Actually was looking more into something like this: http://mkahawa.sourceforge.net/ Thanks to Mary for providing the link.

Comment: I am working on a product proposal for remote-access management. I would be very interested in your (more detailed) requirements ..

Comment: I am currently evaluating _Mkahawa Cyber Manager_, for **Ubuntu 11.10**. It looks quite good, although I am also looking for additional features not yet present.

Comment: Why Ubuntu **11.04**, vs **10.04.3 LTS** or latest (**11.10**)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a miracle (Because I never found something to control a Cyber Cafe, I was provided with this: http://mkahawa.sourceforge.net/

Which is exactly what I was looking for:

[image]

[image]

[image]

It even has packages for Ubuntu: http://mkahawa.sourceforge.net/downloads.php

Comment: I am currently evaluating Mkahawa Cyber Manager, for Ubuntu 11.10.  It looks quite good, although I am also looking for additional features not yet present.

Answer (score 1):

I have also found mkahawa is the only one as Free software out there which is not too old, and provides many features. I don't know yet if all needed features are fulfilled, or even if the features it has all work well. I don't have yet experience with it.

However, as it has been advised to me to use the SVN sources to make it work well in Ubuntu LTS: for now 12.04 Precise, I have also put up a light version of Ubuntu with Openbox (which has been worked on prior, during several months as a contribution). Those who would be eventually interested can read about it starting from here: [Ubuntu with Openbox, easy features and Mkahawa in it](https://sourceforge.net/p/mkahawa/discussion/955736/thread/565810d8)