# How to manage a cyber cafe on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: networking

I have a cyber cafe and I want a cyber cafe management tool, One like Handycafe or EasyCafe. i tried instlling mkahawa but it seems that it does not run on Ubuntu 14.04. Is there any other way to control clients from server?

Comment: 1. This topic from our own Oli to create a kiosk computer takes less than 1/2 hour: http://thepcspy.com/read/building-a-kiosk-computer-ubuntu-1404-chrome/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+OliUbuntu+%28Oli%27s+blog%29&utm_content=FaceBook

Comment: 2. http://mkahawa.sourceforge.net/downloads.php has installers for Ubuntu and it seems the only option; i found topics on the web claiming it works in 13.04. That should mean it works in 14.04/14.10 too though maybe not without some hitches. Dupe: http://askubuntu.com/questions/47640/is-there-a-cyber-cafe-program-for-server-client-places-internet-cafe

Comment: I would advice to post separate questions with what does not work when installing mkahawa. Getting it to work would be the best option since this software seems to be the only one in its genre.