# Kiosk Mode Coding in Chromium

Tags: chromium, browser, setup, kiosk

I don't know how easy this would be, since I don't know anything about it, but I need an Ubuntu setup where the machine boots up, displays the login for a few seconds allowing a chance to log in as an admin, and then precedes to automatically log in to a user account which directly opens Chromium (any other browser is acceptable) in a kiosk mode where only the web content is visible, all Chromium keyboard shortcuts are disabled, and all but a select few websites are blocked, redirecting back to the home page after an "Unauthorized web page" warning comes up if the URL constraint is violated. Is it possible to code a kiosk setup like this, or am I asking for too much? If I'm simply uninformed, and there is already much documentation on anything like this, please redirect me to an appropriate page. If you can code or set up something like my description, please reply with step-by-step instructions, and instructions on how to modify the elements of the kiosk mode. Thank you in advance for any help.

(Note: I'm currently using Ubuntu 10.04, but any distribution would work.)

Comment: Does it need to be Chromium? I have instructions for a Opera web kiosk. http://askubuntu.com/questions/46957/how-do-i-set-up-an-opera-web-kiosk

Comment: Yes having it chromium would be superawesome!!!

Comment: You can launch the full screen chromium with the --kiosk flag, see http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/ for a full list of command line flags

Comment: Possible duplicate http://askubuntu.com/questions/132262/booting-in-kiosk-mode

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that.