# Booting in kiosk mode

Tags: startup, kiosk

How can we configure the machine to boot directly into a restricted interface, with limited options that we can configure? This is to make a kiosk machine.

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]. This site is in English, so I've translated your question into English.

Comment: sorry, my English is not so good, my next question will be on english I promise, thanks for translate

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will have to create a customized session at `/usr/share/xsessions` and [Enable Auto-Login](https://askubuntu.com/a/60264/12943).

Example:

1) Open a file (`gksu gedit /usr/share/xsessions/Firefox.desktop`) and paste:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Firefox (No effects)
Comment=This session only opens Firefox
Exec=/usr/bin/firefox -height 1200 -width 1600
Icon=
Type=Application
```

References: [1](http://maketecheasier.com/customize-the-gdm-sessions-list/2010/08/08), [2](https://askubuntu.com/a/54508/12943).

Comment: Could you explain to the OP how to make this session for any program?

Comment: @desgua : Thanks for sharing, it is working like a charm except for one thing. The window doesn't cover the complete screen area. Some area is left on right side and bottom. I tried same with Opera and Chromium, to no avail. I also tried a pyGtk app and used `window.fullScreen()`. That also leaves some area on all sides. I couldn't understand whats the issue.

Comment: Also see question http://askubuntu.com/questions/184610/custom-session-window-does-not-capture-full-screen-area-by-default-12-04