# How do I create a kiosk-mode where only one application runs, no games, etc.?

Tags: security, kiosk, parental-controls

I want to create a Point-of-Sale (PoS) system with Ubuntu. (i.e. cash register).

The system should start with the PoS application, and shutdown when the PoS app is closed. It must be locked down, and allow no other apps to be run, such as games, etc.

Comment: Please see http://askubuntu.com/q/132262/35775

Answer (score 0):

You can change your setting to do the autologin and insert your program on the startup.
If you are looking for something that still running even if you kill it, check how to create a daemon.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your profile to allow for automatic log in here: 
Top Right of Unity Panel click power button
Go to system settings
Then User Accounts

Unlock your profile with your password and change to automatic log in

see this [image: user account profile in system settings]

Comment: what i want to do to prevent user from accessing games or other. so user can only use the machine as POS and nothing else. so when they close the POS and also automatic shutdown the linux