# Running application in "Kiosk mode"

Tags: auto-login, kiosk

I am trying to configure ubuntu to run an application only, without giving the user the ability to access a terminal or any other part of the system. This application is a fullscreen python GUI. I have already seen this thread, [Booting in kiosk mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132262/booting-in-kiosk-mode), but when I tried to this this for my python application, nothing happened.

Also, is it possible to have ubuntu auto-login without a password and automatically decrypt the folder where the application is being launched from. I want to do this to ensure that no one can remove the hard drive from the device and copy the python files over to another system.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Ooops. I figured out why the xsession wasn't launching. I had a & character at the end of the launch script. Sorry.