# Remove or disable users taskbar

Tags: taskbar

is it possible to remove or disable user's taskbar?

I have to setup Ubuntu box, so user can run only web browser and nothing else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `gksudo gedit /usr/share/xsessions/firefox.desktop`, and paste in the following, then save and exit.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Firefox
Comment=This session logs you into Terminal
Exec=/usr/bin/firefox -height xxx width xxx
Icon=
Type=Application
```

You should now have a new session at the login screen, named Firefox, that will autoload Firefox only.

Comment: thank you, very good tip! but in this case Firefox is not maximized, can you tell me how to achieve that?

Comment: See the edit above, and check out [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/132262/booting-in-kiosk-mode) as well.