# How to turn Ubuntu into kiosk mode from a running session?

Tags: scripts, kiosk, mode

Is it possible to turn Ubuntu (12.10 ) into kiosk mode from, for example, a shortcut on the desktop?

As a newbie, how can I
 write this script?

If it isn't clear, you can compare this with a computer that is available at your supermarket where you only can browse one page with the articles in that sector.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Booting in kiosk mode](http://askubuntu.com/questions/132262/booting-in-kiosk-mode)

Comment: So, does your question come down to something like: *"How do I change the current session into kiosk mode in scripting?"*

Comment: @Web-E I believe OP is asking on how to do this in a current running session rather than a selection at boot.

Comment: yes that's my question gertvdijk

Answer (score -1):

You might be better off with a separate login for a visitor.  I've written up a howto of sorts on Ubuntu Forum under Ubuntu Kiosk with Ubuntu 12.04 and XFCE.

Comment: A separate login does not meet the requirement of the OP for keeping the current session, as this requires him to log out and log in again.