# How to create a web browser only session

Tags: users, session

I was recently in a Virgin media shop and was interested to see that they had laptops running Ubuntu for customers to browse the web on. The setup itself was interesting and I'm wondering if anyone knows how to recreate it.  The features were:

Only running Firefox, no other panels or menus

I tried running a terminal (`ctrl+alt+t`) but it gave a message saying the user didn't have permission to access the x server (or something similar)

I realise to recreate this is a function of controlling both user privileges and session parameters but I'm not sure how I would go about it. Any ideas?

Comment: Please don't cross-post between SE sites: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68545/create-a-browser-only-session-ubuntu

Comment: Have a search for "ubuntu kiosk". Like this: http://nexxylove.tumblr.com/post/22690398464/ubuntu-web-kiosk-in-10-easy-steps#_=_

Comment: dupe: http://askubuntu.com/questions/132262/booting-in-kiosk-mode This one might be better: http://askubuntu.com/questions/124759/customize-ubuntu-for-a-library-internet-kiosk