# Is it possible to create a locked down 'dumb terminal' with ubuntu?

Tags: security

My company has a large amount of document review work that must be done manually by temp workers. The work is done on our website, accessible via VPN only.

We are planning to just show scanned images of the documents on the webpages (page by page), without allowing to download the document file locally.

However, I am worried that a person can take a screen shot of a web page on the computer and somehow store it on USB drive or send via gmail. (I am not worried about using a smartphone cell phone or camera to take a screenshot, let's say the user does not have them)

My question is: has anyone configured an ubuntu installation without any 'escape routes' for the information accessed on it via web browser? Or, to put it another way, an installation where the only thing a person can do is open a specific url in a browser and do nothing else?

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/132262/booting-in-kiosk-mode and  http://askubuntu.com/questions/124759/customize-ubuntu-for-a-library-internet-kiosk and check if any of these setups meet your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Sure I did something similar to this. What you can do is use LiveCDCustomization to remove packages you don't want.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization

What I'd do is set network rules to only allow the live USB's to access your companies IP. But if they need to use the internet I'd set up a limited user account which has nothing but Firefox in it. I'd use SElinux for this. Also use Xubuntu as the base ISO.