# Xubuntu 14.04 disable desktop and panel

Tags: xubuntu

I'm looking to test a Xubuntu 14.04 in the Library public lab.  I'm looking for an option to disable right click on the panel and desktop.

I google it and found something about the locking the panel: https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/xfce#TOC-Lock-the-panels-kiosk-mode-

but this doesn't really work as expected.  My goal is to create a separate public account for xubuntu and had the public log on automatically.  The public user account will be restrict to create folders on desktop or disable right click on desktop and disable right click on panel or disable adding new icons on panel.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

As noted by [Xubuntu Project Leader in the #xubuntu-devel IRC channel](http://irclogs.ubuntu.com/2014/08/31/%23xubuntu-devel.html#t01:00), kiosk mode is not well supported in Xfce and is not a use-case that is considered high priority.  The [Xubuntu Technical Leader noted](http://irclogs.ubuntu.com/2014/08/31/%23xubuntu-devel.html#t01:03) in #xubuntu-devel that write-locking xfconf may solve the right-click issue.

Answer (score -1):

I think you're looking for something like kiosk mode.  Here's a link:

[Booting in kiosk mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132262/booting-in-kiosk-mode)

Answer (score -1):

Xubuntu has, by default, a guest account that probably does exactly what you want. No change is permanent, because it's all in the RAM and the hard disk isn't touched by any changes the user makes.

Logging out and in again, will provide a brand new clean guest account. Ideal for kiosk situations....